# What should be time of prayer

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, adhan

Assalamualaikum everyone,

My question is very basic and i need some clarity.
I have an application in my phone which sounds out Allah O Akbar when it's time for a certain salat. But that is mostly a few minutes ahead of local azan. For instance the loacal moazzin sounds recites the asar azan at 5:15, but the app sounds at 5:3 pm.
I'm used to praying at home these days being unable to hear azan mostly an also because of the Covid. My question is, since my phone is always at my side, I'm always alerted to azan timings and following those is more convenient for me. Should i follow them or the moazzin?

Thanks and may Allah bless you all.

Comment: Every app uses different prayer time calculation methods, all of these methods only work well for the specfic area they are made for. You should follow the local adhan in any case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are living in a place where you hear the muazzin you will take this as reference. Traditional conventions concerning prayer time are not precise to minutes like an app, so 15 minutes are already quite precise.
Asr has even two different definitions according to the school, so the app need not calculate the same way the muazzin does.